# Passing variables to another class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to pass two String variables to another class in flutter and used it. I tried but failed.

I tried this way but it said; Instance member can't be accessed using static. I want to know the right way to do it.

In MyHome class; I passed litemspage0[index] and litemsname0[index] to VideoPlayer0 class

```
    _getPage(int page) {
switch (page) {
  case 0:
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return new Padding(
          padding:
              new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 16.0),
          child: new Card(
            elevation: 2.0,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(16.0)),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
          new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) {
              return new VideoPlayer0(litemspage0[index],litemsname0[index]);
            },
          ),
        );
```

I want to use litemspage0[index],litemsname0[index] in VideoPlayer0 class.
Here is the code I tried,

```
        class VideoPlayer0 extends StatefulWidget {

  final String litemspage0;
  final String litemsname0;

  VideoPlayer0(this.litemspage0, this.litemsname0);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState0 createState() => _MyHomePageState0();
}

class _MyHomePageState0 extends State<VideoPlayer0> {

  static const platform = const MethodChannel("www.youtube.com");
  TextEditingController _idController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _seekToController = TextEditingController();
  double _volume = 1.0;
  VideoPlayerController _videoController;
  String position = "Get Current Position";
  String status = "Get Player Status";
  String videoDuration = "Get Video Duration";
  String _source = VideoPlayer0.litemspage0;
  bool isMute = false;
```

But I'm getting this error.

```
String _source = VideoPlayer0.litemspage0;

Instance member 'litemspage0' can't be accessed using static access.
```

I want to know the proper way to pass variables in one class to another in flutter.

Comment: To access state in stateful widget, you need to access by calling `widget`  like `widget.litemsname0`

Comment: I tried it. But getting an error.  ````Only static members can be accessed in initializers.````

Comment: Error in ````String _source = widget.litemspage0;```` widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your state class, in order to access the variables of the widget class, you’ll have to use `widget`. So in your case, use `widget.litemspage0`.

In addition, you’ll have to assign `_source` in `initState()` like so:

```
String _source;

@override
initState() {
  super.initState();
  _source = widget.litemspage0;
}
```

Comment: I tried it. But getting an error.  ````Only static members can be accessed in initializers.````

Comment: Error in ````String _source = widget.litemspage0;```` widget

Answer (score 1):

That's not the right way to pass variables to another class .
the right way goes like this :

```
VideoPlayer0(litemspage0: yourPageValue  ,litemsname0:yourNameValue);
```

and you can access them in the state class like that :

```
String _source = widget.litemspage0;
```

Comment: The constructor doesn't contains optional variables. In that case, named parameters in function calls are invalid!.

Comment: actually the constructor contain optional variables.so if you want it to be not optional you should add @required before this.variable

Comment: Oh! didn't knew that. Thanks for clarification!